# Drupal 7 - Is there a possibility to create a revision programmatically without publishing it and maintain original node publish?

Tags: drupal-7

I'm working with Drupal 7 and I need to save programmatically a draft node without publishing it but maintain the original node published. I created a new button and when someone clicks on it a function on a custom module try to create a node revision but I have no idea how to do what I wrote up

The user can save as draft the node without lost the originally published node that must be visible to the public view. The save draft must be unpublish and visible only to User owner that can change the node until it will send the request to the administrator to approve the draft node

Someone can tell me how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like the Save Draft module work? It sounds pretty close to your description.

https://www.drupal.org/project/save_draft

Comment: I tried this module but it doesn't work as I want. As I said I have a published node. The user can save as draft the node without lost the originally published node that must be visible to the public view . The save draft must be unpublish and visible only to User owner that can change the node until it will send the request to the administrator to approve the draft node

Comment: I see - you are looking for revisions and workflow. https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning. There is a little complexity involved, but it will handle your entire editing, revision and approval workflow.

Comment: I tried also these two modules but I didn't resolve it. Because if I do not publish the revision, drupal make it as default and the original node becomes with status 0. Do you think there is the possibility of these two modules together to resolve my problem?

Comment: I was thinking to do it programmatically by a function on my module where I create a revision with something like this:
<code>
$nid = $form_state['node']->nid;
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->revision = TRUE; // create a new revision upon saving
$node->revision_moderation = TRUE; // make the new revision pending review
$node = node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state);
$insert = empty($node->nid);
node_save($node);
</code>
but I don't know how to save all data as revision. After this, I can try to restore as default the original node and make status 0 the revision

Comment: I found a bug in the issue queue that may address the problem you are having. It is patched in the dev version of the module. It might be worthwhile to give that a try.

If you really want to write your own module, then use the helper function _node_save_revision. It takes an nid, uid to create the revision. The revision will be available node->vid. You don't have to worry about building the node or gathering data. It is all built in.

Comment: You found a patched in what kind of module? revisioning? save_draft? or what? Can you send me a link about it? 

I'm not an expert programmer of drupal so you said that I can use _node_save_revision on my module to save all data of node in revision mode without doing some like <code> $nid = $form_state['node']->nid; $node = node_load($nid); $node->revision = TRUE; // create a new revision upon saving $node->revision_moderation = TRUE;  .... ?

Comment: My apologies - it is the revisioning module. You mentioned that you tried it and had an issue that appears to be fixed in the dev branch. If you really want to make your own module, I recommend looking at the source to see how it is used - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7.x. You might also want to look at the code of the revisioning module for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Workbench moderation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation)

It's in core for Drupal 8 (since 8.2).
In Drupal 7 it gives you a simple admin interface,  documentation to help you get going and it appears tried-N-true in the community.